# Restarting MySQL server on localhost without restarting PC

Tags: mysql

I installed MySQL and I've been able to run queries using a site I created in Django.  I recently had to abort mysql in task manager because one of my queries was taking too long to respond.

I'm now unable to restart the server.  I've tried running mysqld as described in the mysql docs, but this brings up a commandline window which closes immediately.

Is there a way I can restart my server without restarting my PC?

Comment: Are you running windows?

Comment: It should be registered as a Service.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows:

```
net stop MySQL
net start MySQL
```

In Ubuntu:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

In MacOS:

```
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM stop
sudo /Library/StartupItems/MySQLCOM/MySQLCOM start
```

Comment: I'm using Windows.  I've tried this command in the mysql, mysql server, and the bin directory but I'm getting a "system cannot find the file specified". error

Comment: I'm still getting System Error 2

Comment: Are you connecting remotely? That error is a "file not found" error message. I just ran those commands successfully from my PC without any issues.

Comment: No, I'm running a MySQL server on my machine so I can debug a website I'm creating in Django.

Comment: I can't kill the server using the stop command given above.  It says the service isn't running despite mysqld.exe running.  I'm not sure what's going on here, I'm very new to mysql.

Comment: Have you tried just starting it? If it's not running you shouldn't have to stop it...

Answer (score 0):

In the future you can kill stuck queries without aborting mysql

Create a .bat to open the mysql console (change the directory to suit your needs):

```
cd C:\xampp\mysql\bin
mysql database_name --host=localhost --user=name --password
```

Get the list of processes:

```
show full processlist;
```

Kill the process that is stuck:

```
kill 12345;
```

No restart required ^^.

Comment: This is assuming he is running on xampp

Comment: He can change the directory to whatever he's using.

Answer (score 0):

in windows use the below commands in the command prompt window
however you should run the cmd.exe as an administrator

net stop MySQL

net start MySQL